# In Java how can I format a Time of HHMM to HH:MM AM/PM

Tags: java, time, format

I have a time in the format `HHMM` (1643) and I want it to be formatted to `HH:MM AM/PM` (04:43 PM)

How can I achieve this in Java?

I'm doing something similar for the date which is formatted `YYYMMDD` (20201013) into `MM/DD/YYY` (10/13/2020) with this code:

```
new java.text.SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd").parse($F{date})
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `DateTimeFormatter` & `LocalTime` from [java.time](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/package-summary.html)

First, parse the time as `LocalTime` using `DateTimeFormatter`. Then again format the `LocalTime` into String in your desire format.

```
LocalTime time = LocalTime.parse("1643", DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("HHmm"));
String formattedTime = time.format(DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("hh:mm a"));
System.err.println(formattedTime);
```

Output: `04:43 PM`